# Python split OR loop OR str function running outofIndex dealing with big list - works okay with shorter list

Tags: python, string, list, loops

I used simple string conversion function from list (dict actually) and string function runs out of index due (it ends up with None for one of the input). Below function call kills it when it encounters bad string

```
test_s=s_i.split("Inv/", 1)[1].split(">",1)[0]
```

Q1) My loop breaks at split, and splits spits out list Index out of range error. How do I make it skip this string, display a warning, still continue to concatenate strings with +?
OR can you please help suggest better method, to do this split?

Q2) How to I troubleshoot split? (i.e. how do I debug this)

Q3) Also, how do I input (prompt a python user input prompt) the same list in python?

Below is the code i am trying to run:
Sample input - it is actually list of 100+ items:

```
a_dict={'1234': <Batman:/Inv/Batman/xyzhash>,'4567': <Superman:/Inv/Superman/xyzhash, ..100 more items>

test_f=""
test_s=""
s_i=""

for ind_values in a_dict.values():
    s_i=str(ind_values)  
    test_s=s_i.split("Inv/", 1)[1].split(">",1)[0]
    test_f +=test_s+","
```

`s_i=str(ind_values)`  is the line number 26, but i think it's blowing on `test_s=s_i.split("Inv/", 1)[1].split(">",1)[0]`.

```
Error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 26, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: 100+ items is not huge

Comment: You have a lot jammed into `test_s=s_i.split("Inv/", 1)[1].split(">",1)[0]` - one of those lists is shorter than you think, maybe try some debugging there.

Comment: You should post a full traceback. That will *sho*w you the actual line that has the error.

Comment: `list_with_hundreds_of_items` appears to be a `dict`?

Comment: What is `a_list`? If you're calling `values` on it, I'm pretty sure it's not a list...

Comment: @KMeta. Please provide a complete runnable example that I can paste into my console and run.

Comment: >>> type(s_i)
<type 'str'>
>>> type(b_list)
<type 'dict'>
>>>

Comment: That error message disagrees with your code; notice how it says `"Instruments/"` where the code you showed says `"Inv/"`?

Comment: File "<pyshell#42>", line 3, in <module> test_s=s_i.split("Inv/", 1)[1].split(">",1)[0] IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Karl Knechtel - thanks. If I tweak my input a_dict into curated two items dict, code easily works and provides me desired output. I will end up reviewing the actual large string for anomalies. Code I used had different name of variable  and I made copy paste error - please disregard that portion of disagreement. For purpose of our discussion, It is "Inv" Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe and also Mad Physicist!

Answer (score 1):

> `s_i=str(ind_values)` is the line number 26.

No, it is not. The error is on the next line:

```
test_s=s_i.split("Inv/", 1)[1].split(">",1)[0]
```

You can tell because the error message says that a `list index` is `out of range`, and this is the line where you attempt to use an `index` into a `list` - in two places.

The first one is the issue: `s_i.split("Inv/", 1)[1]`. If `"Inv/"` does not appear in the string, then the `.split` call will produce a list with only one item, which has only a `[0]` index and not a `[1]` index. The `1` parameter to `.split` only specifies a *maximum* number of splits, not a *required* number.

Comment: Thanks @Karl Knechtel. I found out that for one of the input key one among dict) is bad and split returns NONE for that. My loop breaks there and splits spits out list Index outofrange error. How do I make it skip this string, display a warning, still continue to concatenate strings with +?  Sorry for late response, unfort stackoverflow was down when we were having conversations.

Comment: *** if s_i.split("Inv/", 1)[1])=None** show error, skip this loop run, and move to next item **